# Looking for advice regarding embedding a report template facility in .Net WPF App

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've just started looking into building a template based reporting facility to exist in an application built in the .Net WPF Framework. Right now I'm investigating possible approaches to investigate/vette/consider.

Basically, the client wants to embed a reporting system into their new WPF based architecture. The system is to include report generation in addition to some level of report design. The end users are essentially researchers/clinicians , so going with a full blown report design system such as DevExpress (which I really like) and Crystal (which I don't) would be overkill.

Essentially the end report would read very much like a MS word document with a list
of research activities and procedures (as opposed to a good ol'financial report).
From a user stand point, I think the design piece has to be very idiot proof to use. We
don't want the end users futzing with things like column headers, and complicated
report ornamentation.

The easiest thing (from a user's standpoint) is to let them create some basic report templates.

Think of this model: you have your display/report area in a panel on the left, and on the right you've got a series of predefined templates, which users can click, drag and place with the report/document design panel.

I know Microsoft Word has some level of support for this somewhere. But solutions I've seen don't seem to fit into the WPF framework. You'd have to embed a winform with your WPF app to support this click and drag behaviour. If possible, I'd rather not have to suck winforms into this WPF if we don't have to.

We really don't want to have to write and support a fully functional home grownreport 
designer (we shouldn't have to).

Do any ideas come to mind in terms of approaches/technologies?
(custom solutions, open source, 3rd party controls, et al)

Has anyone done anything similar?

I got think there's something out there thought aught to be close.

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 0):

Telerik have a good suite for this - if you're interested in third party controls

[Telerik Reporting Controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx?gclid=CMrm_trlkbQCFePHtAodn2cA4A)

Comment: I looked at Telerik briefly and I saw a standalone report designer and an embedded report viewer. Do they have a report designer control (either WPF or Winforms based) which can be embedded directly into an application? I need something that won't be too difficult to customize behaviour. I will look at it again. JB

Comment: You can indeed embed the report into WPF... See here http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting/report-embedding.aspx#wpf

Comment: Which is not actually what you asked is it? I did have a look around but was unable to find a control with designer can than be embedded in WPF.

Comment: I spoke with the folks from Telerik yesterday and they confirmed what I said above. Their designer is a stand alone exe.